# 画像の自動フォルダ分けについて

Tags: python

画像に大量に保管したアニメのキャプチャ画像があるのですが、キャラクター毎に自動でフォルダ分けするようなアプリやプログラムってありますでしょうか？
可能であれば、google colabでプログラム組みたいのですがご教授頂ければと思います。

Answer (score 0):

こんばんは
アニメの顔で精度が出るは怪しいですが、こちらのリポジトリで顔を自動でファイル分けさせることはできます。
[リポジトリのリンク](https://github.com/tyunh-lab/-AI)
google colabでGPUを使用し、キャプチャ画像の入っているディレクトリで回してみてください。
お役に立てられたら幸いです。